# What makes VLC and Google Chome succeed where MPlayer and OpenCV fail?

Tags: google-chrome, streaming, vlc-media-player, opencv, mjpeg

I have this MJPEG stream. When I open it with VLC or with Chrome, it works perfectly, and in both cases the stream starts instantly (or atleast within one second). However, with MPlayer, I get this message about 1000 times:
Cache not filling, consider increasing -cache and/or -cache-min!
... and then, years later, I might get a stream.

With OpenCV and its captureFromFile, it times out on the analyze duration, but then I get an erratic and lagged stream.

What makes VLC and Chrome succeed here, while MPlayer and OpenCV fail horribly? I tried running VLC with -v, but there is no telling what it does from that.

Comment: Different CODECs?

Answer (score 2):

VLC has all the CODEC embeded and does not share them with the OS.  MPlayer and others rely on CODEC that the OS has.

Comment: Is there a way of outputting whta CODEC VLC uses?

Comment: I found it, but MPlayer gets the cache failure (and the long startup delay) no matter what settings I use.

Comment: @cybernard: What about Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the cache value -cache=4096 for example... also try to inrease the -cache-min=80 (increase by 80%)

Comment: Can you explain *why* this is a solution.